# How to color a word in livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to replace `"organisation"` with `"organization"` and change the color of organization to red in Livecode. Iam using this code for replacement:

```
--replace "organisation" with "organization" in field "MytextField"---
```

but i am not able to change the color of "organization". How this possible?
Is there any option of replacing and coloring "organization" in a sigle code line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this handler

```
on replace_and_highlight pFieldName, pTarget, pReplacement, pColor
   set the caseSensitive to true
   put the length of pTarget      into tTargetLength
   put the length of pReplacement into tReplacementLength
   repeat
      put offset(pTarget, field pFieldName) into tStart
      if tStart is 0 then EXIT repeat
      put pReplacement into     char tStart to \
            tStart + tTargetLength      - 1 of field pFieldName
      set the foregroundColor of char tStart to \
            tStart + tReplacementLength - 1 of field pFieldName to pColor
   end repeat
end replace_and_highlight
```

Example

```
on mouseUp
   -- replace plurals first, invert to see why
   replace_and_highlight "Data", "Organisations", "Organizations", red 
   replace_and_highlight "Data", "organisations", "organizations", red
   replace_and_highlight "Data", "Organisation" , "Organization" , red
   replace_and_highlight "Data", "organisation" , "organization" , red

end mouseUp
```

Comment: To Shalu s: please vote my comment up if, as you write, "It's working thank you for your information".

Answer (score 1):

You can't just tell LiveCode to change the colour of "organization" (or "oranges" for that matter). A quick way to do this is:

```
put the htmlText of field "myTextField"" into myHtml
set the caseSensitive to true
replace "organisation" with "<font color=" & quote & "red" & quote & ">organization</font>" in myHtml
replace "Organisation" with "<font color=" & quote & "red" & quote & ">Organization</font>" in myHtml
set the htmlText of fld "myTextField" to myHtml
```

This is particularly useful if you have multiple instances of the word "organisation". Note that this code replaces the word and adds colour to it simultaneously.

If you want to replace only 1 instance of the word, you could also do the following:

```
set the caseSensitive to true
repeat for each item myWord in "organisation,Organisation"
  put wordoffset(myWord ,field "myTextField") into myOffset
  put "z" into char 7 of word myOffset of field "myTextField"
  set the textColor of word myOffset of fld "myTextField" to red
end repeat
```

This script finds the location of the word and changes the s into a z and applies the colour to it. The order is important. If you do it the other way around, you'll get a black z within a red word.